# How do I get the Yes Chef Dojo in Fruit Ninja?

Tags: ios, fruit-ninja

I received a mission in Fruit Ninja to "Play in the Yes Chef!™ Dojo dojo".  But that's not one of the dojos in the list.  How do I get it?

I have Yes Chef installed also, but I don't see anything in there about Fruit Ninja.  Here's a screen shot of my Yes Chef main map. (I cropped out the top controls for cash, coins, & energy.)

[image: Yes Chef screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it without playing Yes Chef.

1. Bring up this post on your iOS or Android device
2. [Click here to unlock the dojo](http://r.fruitninja.com/?giftCampaign=YesChefInstallXPromoDojo&giftId=YesChefInstallGift5)

If Fruit Ninja is installed, the app should open, and the dojo will be unlocked. Otherwise that link will just go to iTunes.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works.  (I suspect the other answers would work if I connected both games to Facebook, but I don't use Facebook.)

Comment: @cjm You don't need Facebook. There's a menu in YC where you have to redeem your bonuses after completing certain levels, which would be the legit answer. This is easier though.

Comment: Where is this menu?  According to the other answers I should have received that bonus by now.

Comment: @cjm When you're on the world map, there's a watermelon button in the lower right corner. At least there should be.

Comment: I don't see any such button.  I've added a screen shot.

Comment: @cjm Yeah, it's not there - it would be above the medals. No idea why it's missing for you. Maybe you do need to link your Facebook account or something after all.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out.  When you reach certain levels in Yes Chef, you will receive certain bonuses in Fruit Ninja, like Bonus Star Fruit, Power Ups and so on, and there are a total of four bonuses to collect.  I can't remember the exact words, but the Yes Chef Dojo in Fruit Ninja is unlocked by reaching level 30 in Yes Chef.  Look out for Mari from Fruit Ninja popping out in Yes Chef to tell you the details.

Comment: After reading this answer, I played some more Yes Chef and just completed level 30 with 3 stars.  Mari didn't show up.  Do I have to link the games to Facebook to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Fruit Ninja
2. Install the game "Yes Chef"
3. Play "Yes Chef"
4. Unlock the first level of "Yes Chef"
5. Unlock some levels in "Yes Chef"
6. Unlock the level 30 (Yes Chef), you will need pass that level
7. Go to the "fruit icon" in Yes Chef
8. Claim the "fruit ninja dojo", (you will need internet or WiFi, or network, etc. For that operation)
9. Open Fruit Ninja
10. Enjoy your new dojo

*I have that dojo, it's funny*

Comment: I've done steps 1-6, but I see no "fruit icon" in Yes Chef.  Where do I find it?